# Run Script after slick slider loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class on body tag after the slick slider loads and after one of the slider has class .class-slide.

HTML

```
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="slide class-slide">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

So after the slick has loaded and if the slide with class .class-slide is active then i need a demo class on tag.

I tried this

```
jQuery(function () {
 if(jQuery(".class-slide").hasClass("slick-active")){
   jQuery(body).addClass('body-class');
 }
```

but since the DOM is already loaded this wont work . How can we fix this ?

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/GjJGAq)

Comment: You want to add "body-class" on current active slide. Right?

Comment: no on the <body> tag itself

Comment: So when the slide with class "class-slide" is active class will added and when other slide is active class will be removed?

Comment: yes exactly that is what i want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please check below code. On every slide afterChange event will fire. And we can check in it that div with class class-slide is active or not. If div with class class-slide is active then class body-class will be added in body otherwise it will be removed.

```
jQuery('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    if(jQuery(".class-slide").hasClass("slick-active")){
       jQuery(body).addClass('body-class');
    }else{
       jQuery(body).removeClass('body-class');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Slick slider has event `init` and can be used like this

```
$('.your-element').on('init', function(event, slick){
    // event subscriber goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait until your first slide has changed, for example if your autoplay speed is set at several seconds, you can use the setPosition event.

```
jQuery('.slider').on('setPosition', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    if(jQuery(".class-slide").hasClass("slick-active")){
       jQuery(body).addClass('body-class');
    }else{
       jQuery(body).removeClass('body-class');
    }
});
```

I tested this and the callback runs right after the slider arranges each slide.